# How to display placeholder Chips within ChipGroup in xml?

Tags: android, xml, material-design, android-chips

I have a layout with a `ChipGroup` whose chips will be populated programmatically, but I want to visualise how chips will look like within the layout, is there a way to show fake chips like for example using the `tools` namespace?

Comment: Need it too, did you find something @glisu ?

Answer (score 0):

Not really the solution, you asked for, but it gets the job done.
If someone's got a better solution, let me know.

I solved it with a hardcoded chip, which has the visibility set to GONE and inside the tools namespace visibility set to VISIBLE.

```
   <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        tools:text="Leichter Genuss" />
```